# NSOutlineView spring load expanded item

Tags: nsoutlineview

I have a subclass of NSOutlineView implementing the NSSpringLoadingDestination protocol.

Everything works great. The only issue is when I try to drag an item over an already expanded item, spring loading never activates.

The NSOutlineViewDelegateProtocol method outlineView(_:shouldExpandItem:) returns true.

The method outlineView(_:validateDrop:proposedItem:proposedChildIndex:) returns a valid NSDragOperation. The expanded item becomes highlighted when I drag over it.

And the NSSpringLoadingDestination method springLoadingUpdated(_:) returns .enabled

But springLoadingActivated(_:draggingInfo:) is never called.

Oddly, if I do something in springLoadingUpdated(*:) like test isItemExpanded(*:) and immediately close it, spring loading activates as expected. But that's not a solution.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried this but springloading doesn't work on leaves. How did you make this work?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have mentioned that I was trying to spring load a branch that had already been expanded with that triangular disclosure button. I’m not trying to spring load a leaf.

Comment: Where does spring loading work, on auto expanding rows only? It could be a bug in the drag & drop implementation of `NSOutlineView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a `NSOutlineView` that is a `NSSpringLoadingDestination` to correctly call `springLoadingActivated(_:draggingInfo:)` by overriding the `NSOutlineView` function `isExpandable` to return true.

`override func isExpandable(_ item: Any?) -> Bool { return true }`