# Spring load NSOutlineView leaf rows

Tags: swift, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview

I've subclassed `NSOutlineView` and implemented `NSSpringLoadingDestination`, but `springLoadingActivated()` is only ever called on non-leaf rows, even though I've implemented `springLoadingEntered()` and `springLoadingUpdated()` to indiscriminately return `[.enabled]`. I assume `NSOutlineView`'s built-in drag & drop support is interfering with my attempts. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Duplicate of [NSOutlineView spring load expanded item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174641/nsoutlineview-spring-load-expanded-item). Do you need drag & drop?

Comment: Springload the rows instead of the outline view?

Comment: I do need drag & drop, and when I spring load the rows, they hijack the drag/drop messages from the outline view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feels a little hacky, but it seems I can get away with this by spring loading the rows, but also overriding all of the `NSDraggingDestination` methods to pass the word on to the parent `NSOutlineView`:

```
class SpringLoadedOutlineRow: NSTableCellView, NSSpringLoadingDestination {
    var outlineView: NSOutlineView! {
        didSet {
            registerForDraggedTypes(outlineView.registeredDraggedTypes)
        }
    }

    //Pass through `NSDraggingDestination` methods so we don't interfere with `NSOutlineView`
    override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        return outlineView.draggingEntered(sender)
    }
    override func prepareForDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        return outlineView.prepareForDragOperation(sender)
    }
    override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        return outlineView.performDragOperation(sender)
    }
    override func concludeDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        outlineView.concludeDragOperation(sender)
    }
    override func draggingExited(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        outlineView.draggingExited(sender)
    }

    //Only pass through if we're expandable & not yet expanded (to get `NSOutlineView`'s default disclosure spring-loading); otherwise it will eat our leaf spring-loading
    override func draggingUpdated(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        guard let representedItem = outlineView.item(atRow: outlineView.row(for: self)) else { return outlineView.draggingUpdated(sender) }
        if outlineView.isExpandable(representedItem) && !outlineView.isItemExpanded(representedItem) {
            return outlineView.draggingUpdated(sender)
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }

    //Actually spring-load!
    func springLoadingActivated(_ activated: Bool, draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo) {
        //Whatever you want
    }

    func springLoadingHighlightChanged(_ draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo) {

    }

    func springLoadingEntered(_ draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSSpringLoadingOptions {
        return [.enabled]
    }

    func springLoadingUpdated(_ draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSSpringLoadingOptions {
        return [.enabled]
    }
}
```